# fix position div on top of parent so it doesn't move on resize

Tags: html, css

I know there is a lot of discussion out there on this topic, and I've read a lot and tired a number of things. This tutorial was very helpful http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101 with some of my other pages. But this one is throwing me. 
I'm trying to position the #mainwrapper central and on top on top of the #bubble div. I have achieved this by specifying the position with top:200px ect. But when resizing the window everything moves. I've fixed the issue on other pages by position using relative positioning. Howver when I tried that on this page it hides the #mainwrapper behind the #bubble.
Really stuck!

```
<div id="bubble"> 
<div class="content">
<div class ="nav_image">
    <img src="../navbar/backbar.gif" height="114"/><br />
            <nav>
                    <ul>
                    <li class='active'><a href="../homepage.htm"class="nav1">Home</a></li>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href="cottages.htm"class="nav1">Cottages</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="farmhouse/farmhouse.htm"class="nav1">Farmhouse</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="farmhouse/facilities.htm"class="nav1">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="farmhouse/guest book.htm"class="nav1">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="farmhouse/booking rates.htm"class="nav1">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="the barn/the barn.htm"class="nav1">The Barn</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="the barn/facilities.htm"class="nav1">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="the barn/guest book.htm"class="nav1">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="the barn/booking rates.htm"class="nav1">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="granary/granary.htm"class="nav1">Granary</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="granary/facilities.htm"class="nav1">Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="granary/guest book.htm"class="nav1">Guest Book</a></li>
                            <li><a href="granary/booking rates.htm"class="nav1">Booking Rates</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>

                <li><a href="../croyde.htm"class="nav1">Croyde</a></li>
            <li><a href="../contactus.htm"class="nav1">Contact us</a></li>                      
</ul>                   
</nav>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
     <div id="box-1" class="box">  
   <a href="farmhouse/farmhouse.htm"><img id="image-1" src="030.jpg"/></a>
        <span class="caption simple-caption">  
        <a href="farmhouse/farmhouse.htm" class="span">The Farmhouse</a> 
        </span>  
    </div>
       <div id="box-2" class="box">  
        <a href="the barn/the barn.htm"><img id="image-2" src="040.jpg"/></a>  
        <span class="caption simple-caption">  
        <a href="the barn/the barn.htm" class ="span">The Barn</a>   
        </span>  
    </div>  
     <div id="box-3" class="box">  
        <a href="granary/granary.htm"><img id="image-3" src="038.jpg"/></a>  
        <span class="caption simple-caption">  
        <a href="granary/granary.htm" class="span">The Granary</a>    
        </span>  
</div> 
</div> 
    <div id="bubble2">
    <div class="blurb">
    <img src="../titles/the cottages (Copy).jpg" alt="The Cottages">
    <p>The properties are idyllically situated right in the heart of the picturesque Devon coastal village of Croyde, which has history that stretches over a thousand years to pre-saxon times.</p>
    <p>The Farmhouse & Barn are 17th century Grade II listed and both sleep 6. The Granary is Curtelage listed and sleeps 2. All of the cottages can be rented togther or seperatly as required. The Barn and Farmhouse are ideal for big parties with an interconnecting door which we can arrange to be unlocked.</p>
    <p>The cottages are located centrally in the village, down a small quiet lane just 5 minutes walk to the pubs and eateries and 10 minutes walk to the beautiful sandy beach.</p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #4E5869;
    color: #000;
}
#bubble { 
     width: 1013px; 
     height: 800px;
     left: 6px; 
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-image: url('../images/sea board (Copy).jpg'); 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     position: relative; 
    z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
}

  #mainwrapper {  
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
    width: 740px;
    background: transparant;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px; 
    min-height: 250px;
    height: auto;
    }

    #mainwrapper .box {  
    position: relative; 
    border: 3px solid white;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    height: 225px;  
    float: left;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 225px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    }  
#bubble2{
    position: relative;
     width: 980px; 
     height: 300px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background:white;  
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 90; /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
}  
    #mainwrapper .box img {  
    position: relative;  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    } 
    #mainwrapper .box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
    }  

    #mainwrapper .box .simple-caption {  
        height: 70px;  
        width: 225px;  
        display: block;  
        bottom: -80px;  
        line-height: 15pt;  
        text-align: center;  
    }   
     #mainwrapper .box:hover .simple-caption { 
        -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);  
        -o-transform: translateY(-100%);  
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);  
        transform: translateY(-100%);  
    }  

    #mainwrapper .span {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold; 
}

h1{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}
a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}

/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color: #33CCFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: normal;
}
a:visited {
    color: #0033CC;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; /* this padding mirrors the right padding in the headings and paragraph rule above. Padding was placed on the bottom for space between other elements on the lists and on the left to create the indention. These may be adjusted as you wish. */
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the .container is removed */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Any help would be hreat!
Thanks

Comment: You should make a JSFiddle and strip out as much HTML as possible while still showing us the issue. With all of these broken relative images, it's hard to see what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does adding margin:0 auto; like this?

```
#mainwrapper {
position: relative;
top: 32px;
width: 740px;
background: transparant;
padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
min-height: 250px;
height: auto;

margin:0 auto;
}
```

Does that resolve you're issue? if you're having problems with absolutes falling behind other objects z-index can often be very helpful.

Pen of the above solution here
http://codepen.io/dave_agilepixel/pen/bgjlv

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Sorry been away for a couple of weeks. A combo of both fixes the problem. Thanks again for the advice.